# One number is removed from the set of integers from $1$ to $n.$ The average of the remaining numbers is $163/4.$ Which integer was removed?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations, average

> One number is removed from the set of integers from $1$ to $n.$ The average of the remaining numbers is $\dfrac{163}4$.  Which integer was removed?

**Source.**  [British Mathematical Olympiad 2010/11, Round 1, Problem 1](https://bmos.ukmt.org.uk/home/bmo1-2011.pdf)

I was hoping if someone could spot the flaw in my working for this question.

**Attempt.**

I began by letting the integer that was removed be $x$.

Then: $$\frac{1 + 2 + \cdots + (x-1) + (x+1) +\cdots + n} {n-1} = \frac{163}{4}$$

There is two arithmetic sums in the denominator, the first from 1 to $x$ and the second from $x+1$ to $n$.

These are equal to $\frac{x(x-1)}{2}$ and $\frac{(n-x)(n+x+1)}{2}$, and subbing in to first equation this gives:

$$\frac{x(x-1) + (n-x)(n+x+1)}{2(n-1)} = \frac{163}{4}$$

which reduces to:

$$\frac{n^2 + n - 2x}{2(n-1)} = \frac {163}{4}$$

And then:

$$2(n^2 + n -2x) = 163(n-1)$$

At first I thought you could consider factors, as 163 was prime then:

$n-1 = 2$ giving $n = 3$ and $n^2 + n - 2x = 163$, which using $n=3$ gives $x= -75.5$ which isn't our positive integer.

I then tried considering a quadratic in $n$ and using the discriminant but again that just looked to give a negative value of $x.$ I would be grateful for any help

Comment: Since it’s a contest, could you please give a reference? This way, we’ll know it’s not from an *ongoing* contest.

Comment: It's from BMO 1 2010

Comment: I'd personally start with the fact that the left-hand side is even, so $n$ is odd.

Comment: Similar considerations like that, finding parities, give you what $x$ is in terms of $n$. And then you can solve for $n$ using a quadratic.

Comment: (Can’t check your query because Balkan MO problems apparently aren’t on aops for some reason. Never mind.) Why would you have $n-1=2$? I suggest finding a precise estimate of $\frac{n^2+n-2x}{n-1}$ depending on $n$ only, giving it only a few possible values.

Comment: The conclusion in the sentence starting with ***At first I thought you could consider factors [...]*** is not logical.  You can only see that $n-1$ is a multiple of $2$.  You assumed $n-1=\color{red}2$ and $n=\color{red}3$ (although you wrote $n-1=3$ and $n=2$, so I think you made a few typos there, but it doesn't matter).

Comment: @mindlack it's the British MO, here is a link: https://bmos.ukmt.org.uk/home/bmo1-2011.pdf

Comment: @Batominovski thanks I see the blunder in my logic now

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165013/which-number-was-removed-from-the-first-n-naturals

Comment: $\displaystyle{81 \times \left(81 + 1\right)/2 -\color{red}{ 61}  \over 80} = {163 \over 4}$ with $\displaystyle n = 81$ and $\displaystyle x = 61$.

Answer (score 2):

We know that $n$ is odd. Notice that

$$ n^2 - n \leq n^2 + n -2x \leq n^2 +n - 2 $$

$$ \implies n^2 - n \leq \frac{163}{2}(n-1) \leq n^2 +n - 2  $$

which gives us $n \geq 79.5$ and $n\leq 81.5$, so $n=81$

Answer (score 1):

This is not how you are supposed to solve it, but I feel like cheating. We have the equation $2(n^2+n-2x)=163(n-1)$, and $1\leq x\leq n$.

If you assume that $x=1$ then you solve for $n$ using the quadratic formula, and you obtain $79.5$.

If you assume that $x=n$ then you solve for $n$ you obtain $81.5$. Thus $n=80$ or $n=81$.

If $n=80$ then you can solve for $x$ and obtain $83=4x$, wrong. So $n=81$. Solving again yields $4n=244$, and ding ding, we have a winner.

---

As everyone else seems to have done this in the way I considered cheating, I should expand on the way I initially did it, which is completely different.

We have $2(n^2+n-2x)=163(n-1)$, and $1\leq x\leq n$. We see that $n$ is odd, so $n=2m+1$. Substituting in and cancelling the 2s yields

$$(2m+1)^2+(2m+1)-2x=163m$$
or
$$4m^2+2-2x=157m.$$
Write $y=x-1$ and also, the LHS is even, so $m=2a$ is even. More substituting  and removing the $2$ from both sides yields
$$8a^2-y=157a.$$
The crucial point: we see that $a\mid y$. Since $n=2m+1=4a+1$, and $y$ is a multiple of $a$, $y=\alpha a$ for $\alpha$ between $1$ and $4$. Dividing through by $a$ yields
$$8a-\alpha=157.$$
Taking congruences modulo $8$ yields $\alpha\equiv 3\bmod 8$, so $\alpha=3$. Thus $y=3a$, so $x=3a+1$ and $n=4a+1$. We put this back into the top equation, $2(n^2+n-2x)=163(n-1)$, to obtain $a=20$, so $n=81$, $x=61$.

Comment: It's not really cheating.  Comparing with [Attila1177298's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3768107/72152), I think you two have more-or-less the same solution.  I would upvote both solutions, but I just have no votes left to give to any of you.

Answer (score 1):

The average of $1,2,3,\ldots,n$ is the number halfway between the endpoints, $(n+1)/2,$ so the sum is $n(n+1)/2.$ Omitting $x$ from among $1,2,3,\ldots,n,$ we get the sum $n(n+1)/2-x.$

Thus the average of $1,2,3,\ldots,n$ must be a weighted average of $\big( n(n+1)/2-x\big)/(n-1)$ and $x,$ with respective weights $(n-1)/n$ and $1/n.$
$$
\frac{n-1} n \left( \frac{n(n+1)/2} {n-1} - \frac x {n-1} \right) + \frac 1 n\cdot x = \frac{n+1} 2
$$
Therefore we have:
\begin{align}
& \frac{n-1} n \cdot \frac{163} 4 + \frac x n = \frac{n+1} 2 \\[8pt]
& \frac{n(n+1)}{2(n-1)} - \frac x {n-1} = \frac{163} 4
\end{align}
So we get a system of two equations that is quadratic in $n$ and linear in $x.$ I'd try solving for one of those two in terms of the other and then substituting and solving the remaining equation.

Answer (score 1):

Say you're removing $x$ from the set $1, 2, \ldots, n$.  The average of the resulting numbers will be at least $n/2$ (if you remove $n$) and at most $(n+2)/2$ (if you remove $1$.)  So we have

$$ n/2 \le 163/4 \le (n+2)/2 $$

or, multiplying through by 4,

$$ 2n \le 163 \le 2n+2. $$.

So $n = 81$.  You don't have to explicitly work out the number being removed, but it's $(1 + 2 \ldots + 81) - (163/4) \times 80$ = $(81 \times 82)/2 - (163/4) \times 80 = 61$.

Comment: When you multiply through by $4$, you obtain $2n\le 163\le 2n+4$, leaving two possibilities, $n=80,81$.